# JUnit test cases- setting up data

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have a simple CRUD operation that needs to be unit tested.
These test cases are for the DAO layer- so all tests are against the database and hence can't be mocked.

So I have one test cases for create another for update and another for read.

1. Should I hard code the data in the JUnit class or do you externalize it ?
2. The Read TestCase would obviously need data in the database. Should I depend upon the Create Test cases to set up the data or use a SQL statement for that ?

What is the best-practice on this?

If you can point me to an internet resource which discusses this- that would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Spring has excellent support for this sort of thing](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/testing.html#junit38-legacy-tx) - unit tests that you want to operate against a "test" database, which can be scripted to be re-created on each individual unit test.

The latter part of that last sentence is the key to developing re-usable and extensible unit tests - a unit test against a database should not be forced to rely on the data optimistically being in a certain state, or rely on a previous unit test to run first - you'll want to re-create the database for each unit test so that each test case gets a "clean" version of the data.

The step-by-step tutorial on setting up Spring MVC actually [has a section on setting up unit tests for database classes](http://static.springframework.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part5.html), which I think would be a valuable reference even when you are not using Spring MVC - you can use this as a reference on how to set up the test database to be created/initialized from the build script, using the Spring container to re-load the data on each test run, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using [DBUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/). Allows you to setup a database to a known state using files and has nice comparison with expected results functionality. Getting started guide is [here](http://www.dbunit.org/howto.html).

It's also good practice not perform any commits as part of the testcase and then you can rollback on tearDown().